# lubuntu: alias application-specific initialization failed: file open failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I'm using lubuntu(ubuntu) and have a problem with the alias function when I want to open xampp.

When I type

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

it works fine.

When I create an alias with:

```
alias xampp='/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
```

and then type "xampp" I get an error:

```
application-specific initialization failed: file open failed
```

I'm new to linux and have no idea why this error appears.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `sudo` to your `alias` command like below.

```
alias xampp='sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
```

Now when you type `xampp` if `sudo` session is not active you will be prompted for password.